# How can I use ng-animate with ui-view rather than ng-view?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router, ng-animate

I am using angular-ui-router with angularJS v1.2 and would like to implement custom page transitions.
How can I use ng-animate with ui-view (from [angular-ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)) rather than ng-view (which would be the standard way)? See [Remastered Animation in AngularJS 1.2](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html) for reference on ng-view.

EDIT:
I have tried two different versions of angular: v1.2.0-rc.2 and v1.2.0-rc.3 as suggested in the comments, but neither seems to do the trick. I guess I might be doing something wrong?

Here is the HTML:

```
<div ui-view class="slide"></div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.slide {
    width:1024px;
    height:768px;
}
.slide.ng-enter,
.slide.ng-leave {
    -webkit-transition:0.5s linear all;
    -moz-transition:0.5s linear all;
    -o-transition:0.5s linear all;
    transition:0.5s linear all;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.slide.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

I added a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/perqa/mDVgX/6/) of the previously mentioned example. It would be nice to expand this example to cover ng-view and ui-view, but I'm not sure how to get ng/ui-view and the partials into JSfiddle, though.

Comment: The repository has an `angular-1.2` branch which has code updated to handle animations for 1.2.

Comment: @NateAbele: I tried it, following the CSS animation example in http://www.yearofmoo.com/#how-to-make-animations-in-angularjs, but nothing happens. Is the CSS class naming convention the same for ui-view as for ng-view? Example: .my-special-animation.ng-enter

Comment: Check your version of Angular. They've broken it like twice now.

Comment: And by 'it', I mean the animation API.

Comment: Is there any update on this?  I'm interested in creating soft fades for each ui-router navigation, but it doesn't seem to be working for angular.js and angular-animate 1.2.3 with angular-ui-router 0.2.7.  Hard to find any working examples for latest versions.

Answer (score 35):

The bug is now closed and they've added an entry over at the ui-router [Wiki](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-animate-ui-view-with-ng-animate). It also includes a demo [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/NsZhDL?p=preview). I will copy the code example here, just in case the URL would become outdated.

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="span12 ui-view-container">
      <div class="well" ui-view></div>        
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Have to set height explicity on ui-view 
to prevent collapsing during animation*/
.well[ui-view]{
 height: 65px; 
}

.ui-view-container {
  position: relative;
}

[ui-view].ng-enter, [ui-view].ng-leave {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
    transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
}

[ui-view].ng-enter {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform:scale3d(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
  -moz-transform:scale3d(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
  transform:scale3d(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
}

[ui-view].ng-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform:scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  -moz-transform:scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  transform:scale3d(1, 1, 1);
}

[ui-view].ng-leave {
  opacity: 1; 
  -webkit-transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

[ui-view].ng-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform:translate3d(100px, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform:translate3d(100px, 0, 0);
  transform:translate3d(100px, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: what syntax do you use if you want to limit the animation to one named ui-view?

Comment: Thanks - this answer got me onto the right track solving some very annoying issues with animating my ui-view. 

Some key points to get you animation to look nice, especially the leaving animation.

1. Needs to be in a container thats is set to position: relative;

2. on ng-enter set postition to absolute, and left / right to 0

3. To improve quality have a height set for your UI-View ie min height
for better transitions

Answer (score 7):

Looks like this is fixed with UI Router 0.2.8.
I'm using AngularJS v1.2.7.

For an example, just add the "slide" class to your ui-view

```
<div ui-view class="slide">
```

And use the following css for your animation.

```
.slide {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .7s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform .7s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: -o-transform .7s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform .7s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.slide.ng-enter {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.slide.ng-enter.ng-enter-active, .slide.ng-leave {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.slide.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    transform: translateX(100%);
}
```

Additionally, some animations seemed to have some weird behavior because of $uiViewScroll. I worked around it by adding autoscroll="false" to my ui-view element.

Answer (score 3):

Over the weekend, I created two plunks demonstrating view animations for both `ui-view` and `ng-view`

`ui-view`: http://plnkr.co/edit/jpebBk?p=preview

`ng-view`: http://plnkr.co/edit/LQhVYU?p=preview

[angular-ui-router 0.2.8](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/releases/tag/0.2.8) came with fixes to major view animation bugs

Answer (score 3):

I just posted a [tutorial with a working demo](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/01/20/Angular-ngAnimate-Tutorial-with-UI-Router.aspx) for using ngAnimate (1.4.8) with UI Router.

It shows a couple of different view animations, a fade in transition on the main view and a slide in/out transition on a nested view.

Here's a snippet from the LESS file for the fade in transition on the main view:

```
main {
    /* start 'enter' transition */
    &.ng-enter {
        /* transition on enter for .5s */
        transition: .5s;

        /* start with opacity 0 (invisible) */
        opacity: 0;
    }

    /* end 'enter' transition */
    &.ng-enter-active {
        /* end with opacity 1 (fade in) */
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Avoid the `view` name for `named-views` or `id` for that element**.

For example, if this is your `html`

```
<div id="home-page" ui-view="home">
  <!-- THIS IS WHERE YOUR TEMPLATE WILL BE LOADED -->
</div>
```

Instead of:

```
/*AVOID*/
div#home-page[ui-view="home"].ng-enter {
    /*ENTER STYLES*/
}
div#home-page[ui-view="home"].ng-enter-active {
    /*...ENTER-ACTIVE-STYLES*/
}
```

Try:

```
div[ui-view].ng-enter {
    /*...ENTER-STYLES*/
}
div[ui-view].ng-enter-active {
    /*...ENTER-ACTIVE-STYLES*/
}
```

Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

Like someone said in the post.  there is a angular 1.2 branch of the router that has patches that make it work.  I know for a fact that using Angular 1.2.6 ng-animate 1.2.6 and my special ui-router build of 0.2.0 beta branch 1.2 works...  fading ui-views..  in and out.

the problem is that you need to "build" the beta branch angular router.. you can't just go download a tarball from git and it works.. you have to download it.  then BUILD it.  then you will have a custom ui-router.  look at your ui-router header in javascript.  mine says this..

```
/**
 * State-based routing for AngularJS
 * @version v0.2.0-dev-2013-10-05
 * @link http://angular-ui.github.com/
 * @license MIT License, http://www.opensource.org/licenses/MIT
 */
```

does your's say version 0.2.0-dev-2013-10-05?  that date is the date i compiled mine. so your date should be relevant to yours..    if you don't see that in your header of your javascript then you are just using the same 0.2.0 version as the master, you aren't using anything special to make 1.2 animations work...

here is a pastbin of the compiled ui-router that works with 1.2  try it out.  BOOM!

[0.2.0 Angular-ui-router custom build](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=hfSpURL8)

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone wanted to use [animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) with [Angular](https://angularjs.org/) and [UI-Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router), one could simply do this below. Note this was only tested using Angular 1.2.21 and UI-Router 0.2.10.

Example of using *FadeInDown* as enter animation and *FadeOutDown* as exit animation. Simply swap the animation name for any animation from animate.css. You may also want to put this in a div container with the position set to relative.

HTML:

```
<div data-ui-view class="fade"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.fade.ng-enter, .fade.ng-leave {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-duration: 1s;
}

.fade.ng-enter {
   -webkit-animation-name: fadeInDown;
   animation-name: fadeInDown;
}

.fade.ng-leave {
   -webkit-animation-name: fadeOutDown;
   animation-name: fadeOutDown;
}
```

Another example instead using *bounceInDown* and *bounceOutDown*:

HTML:

```
<div data-ui-view class="bounce"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.bounce.ng-enter, .bounce.ng-leave {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-duration: 1s;
}

.bounce.ng-enter {
   -webkit-animation-name: bounceInDown;
   animation-name: bounceInDown;
}

.bounce.ng-leave {
   -webkit-animation-name: bounceOutDown;
   animation-name: bounceOutDown;
}
```

EDIT: Made a fork of @kamweti's [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wAZZqNCZFJeXV8StzGtz?p=preview) to visualize example with animate.css.

Answer (score 1):

Using AngularMotion https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-motion then just add this to your css...

```
div[ng-view].ng-leave-active {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Add your animation to the class (`am-fade` in my case) of your ng-view div