# how to use animation with Ionic framework's ui-view directive

Tags: angularjs, animation, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic Framework I have a Shell Page(Main Index Page) which will show Some views, that views i want to animate as show inside Shell page. I mean when the view going to be show in shell page it needs to be animate.
I am using these codes to animate my view this is working fine but is there any built-in support available for animating ui-view.???

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="span12 ui-view-container">
      <div class="well" ui-view></div>        
   </div>
</div>
```

here is the css: which i am copy paste from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19514445/how-can-i-use-ng-animate-with-ui-view-rather-than-ng-view)

```
/* Have to set height explicity on ui-view 
to prevent collapsing during animation*/
.well[ui-view]{
 height: 65px; 
}

.ui-view-container {
  position: relative;
}

[ui-view].ng-enter, [ui-view].ng-leave {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
    transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
}

[ui-view].ng-enter {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform:scale3d(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
  -moz-transform:scale3d(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
  transform:scale3d(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
}

[ui-view].ng-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform:scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  -moz-transform:scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  transform:scale3d(1, 1, 1);
}

[ui-view].ng-leave {
  opacity: 1; 
  -webkit-transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

[ui-view].ng-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform:translate3d(100px, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform:translate3d(100px, 0, 0);
  transform:translate3d(100px, 0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `ion-nav-view` instead of `ui-view`:

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/