# ngAnimate ng-leave class not added when changing the state

Tags: angularjs

I'm using UI-Router and trying to implement ngAnimate module animations.

ng-enter works fine. But, I don't see ng-leave being added to the DOM. I understand that class will be added temporarily and removed, but it didn't.

I'm using 
**AngularJS 1.4.7** and **UI Router v0.2.15**

Here's my code:

index.html

```
    <div class="row">
            <form class="form-horizontal form-left" name="formProfile" novalidate ng-controller="profileController">
                    <fieldset>
                        <div id="form-views" ui-view></div>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
    </div>
```

View1.html (This is default view that will be loaded into index.html)

```
<p>View 1 State</p>
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-block btn-cm" ui-sref="create.view2">Next</a>
<div ui-view></div>
```

View2.html

```
 <p>View 2 State</p>
 <a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-block btn-cm">Finish</a>
```

app.js

```
    angular.module('profileModule',['ui.router', 'ngAnimate']);

    angular.module('profileModule').run(['$state',function($state){
    $state.go('create');
    }]);

    angular.module('profileModule').config(['$stateProvider','$locationProvider',function($stateProvider,$locationProvider){
        $stateProvider.state('create', {
            url:'/create',
            templateUrl: 'view1.html',
            controller: 'profileController'
        });

        $stateProvider.state('create.view2', {
            url:'/view2',
            templateUrl: 'view2.html',
        });
        }]);
```

Any suggestions why ng-leave is not being added to `<div id="form-views" ui-view></div>` when create.view2 state is being loaded?

Comment: I may be missing something here, but why is it important that ng-leave is added to the DOM?

Comment: In order to apply the animation, that class will be added by ngAnimation module while the dom being loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your version of ng-animate 1.4.7 as well?? You did not post your CSS. I believe you need to do this to help debug. If you could post a plunker of your issue that would **really** help.

Also if you have not review the animate classNameFilter as it will help speed up your site by only applying animations to defined classes.

$animateProvider.classNameFilter(/animate|ng-toast/);

Here is my CSS and I use the same angular, ng-animate and ui-router:

This plunker / answer gives a great solution:

http://plnkr.co/edit/NsZhDL?p=preview

[How can I use ng-animate with ui-view rather than ng-view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19514445/how-can-i-use-ng-animate-with-ui-view-rather-than-ng-view)

```
/* Have to set height explicity on ui-view 
to prevent collapsing during animation*/
.well[ui-view]{
 height: 65px; 
}

.ui-view-container {
  position: relative;
}

[ui-view].ng-enter, [ui-view].ng-leave {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
    transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
}

[ui-view].ng-enter {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform:scale3d(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
  -moz-transform:scale3d(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
  transform:scale3d(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
}

[ui-view].ng-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform:scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  -moz-transform:scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  transform:scale3d(1, 1, 1);
}

[ui-view].ng-leave {
  opacity: 1;
  /*padding-left: 0px;*/  
  -webkit-transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

[ui-view].ng-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
  /*padding-left: 100px;*/
  -webkit-transform:translate3d(100px, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform:translate3d(100px, 0, 0);
  transform:translate3d(100px, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: I changed the layout of code similar to that plunker and it works fine.